# Devise + Omniauth - How to pass extra parameters along?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the ability in the app to load /users/auth/facebook to connect to facebook. I want to be able to know where the request came from. Whether it was from a user who is registering with facebook, or a existing user who simply wants to connect with facebook. Based on the type, the responses are very different.

How can I pass a param along to omniauth when authenticating. I tried doing:

```
/users/auth/facebook?connect_action=signup_connect_to_facebook
```

But that connect_action param didn't make it when it hit AuthenticationsController#Create

Ideas? Thansk

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You have to use the `:params` options, as in

```
omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, var: 'value', var2: 'value2' )
```

and later in the callback you can access `request.env['omniauth.params']` to get the hash! :)

Comment: This would ideally work but there is a bug in the code!
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/543

So, I just assigned the value to my session, and cleared it on callback :)

Comment: I'm using it, not problem whatsoever! (1.1.0)

Comment: What are you referring to by "in the callback"?

Comment: Additional Information: 1. The link with path `omniauth_authorize_path` calls the method `def facebook` in `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController` which calls another method `from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])`. So in `def facebook` you can find them at `request.env["omniauth.params"]`, NOT inside the `["omniauth.auth"]`.  If you want to use them in `from_omniauth`, you need to pass them to the method with `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], request.env["omniauth.params"])`

Answer (score 9):

If the request is made from different pages in your application, you can examine the request.env['omniauth.origin']. Omniauth saves this variable automatically.

[Here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Saving-User-Location) is a more detailed explanation

As far as passing custom parameters, I have tried to do this unsuccessfully. The workaround is to store it in the session before going to the provider as explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/omniauth/browse_thread/thread/4d99d608af904879).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Does omniauth + devise suports it?

Comment: Yeap, Im using this in my app with both devise and omniauth

Comment: I used this approach before landing on this post. But I phased it out as the solution suggested by @fuzzyalej worked and looks cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately, just saves url without anchor part, does not serve for my use case, but I think this is great.

Answer (score 0):

For facebook use the 'state' parameter and pass what you want, but don't forget the encode.

```
/users/auth/facebook?state=parameter
```

You could send the parameter as a url form encoded json and then in the callback parse it.

Comment: The `state` parameter should only be used to pass cross-site request forgery (CSRF) tokens.