# Passing random url params to OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using omniauth with devise and I'm wondering how to pass url params and access them.

Here's a link example: `/accounts/auth/facebook?do_something_after_return=1`
Now I want to be able to retrieve this `do_something_after_return` in the callback. I don't care if it's saved in session or elsewhere. Problem is, I don't know where can I intercept this param.

What is the controller and the action that link `/accounts/auth/facebook` points to?
Routes tell me nothing, it's simply not there. All I have in the routes is this `/accounts/auth/:provider(.:format {:controller=>"accounts/omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru"}` which is a callback.

Comment: See also: [Devise + Omniauth - How to pass extra parameters along?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Params are captured in `env["omniauth.params"]`.

Comment: I am able to do it without the env. I can access them directly through the params hash.

Comment: Where is this documented?