# Passing parameters through OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I need to pass some parameters to callback action. Judging from the source code, OmniAuth should add query string to callback URL but strangely it does not. When I open

```
/auth/facebook?from=partner
```

...and get redirected to Facebook, `return_url` is just

```
/auth/facebook/callback
```

...without any parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999907/passing-random-url-params-to-omniauth

Comment: Your "from" parameter can be retrieved through env["omniauth.params"]

Comment: See also if using Devise: [Devise + Omniauth - How to pass extra parameters along?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along)

Answer (score 82):

After struggling with all the above answers, I figured out what to do regarding **Facebook**, which by default does not display the params in `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`.

So -- If you are using a query string for the callback, similar to something like this:

```
"/auth/facebook?website_id=#{@website.id}"
```

The only way to get that website_id param is by using `request.env["omniauth.params"]`. **NOTE:  MAKE SURE YOU USE omniauth.params and not omniauth.auth -- this one tripped me up for a while**.

Then, to test this out, you can inspect it within your controller action (notice the RAISE line...):

```
def create
  raise request.env["omniauth.params"].to_yaml 
  # the rest of your create action code...
end
```

You should see your parameter there.  Great. Now, go back to your controller and remove that RAISE line. Then, you can access the param as follows in your controller action:

```
params = request.env["omniauth.params"]
website_id = params["website_id"]
```

NOTE:  in params["website_id"] you need to use quotes and NOT a symbol.

Comment: I got output in omniauth.auth but nil in omniauth.params. What is wrong? i already pass parameter in URL. "/auth/facebook/state=123"

Comment: @harsh4u probably because your URL is lacking a '?' before the parameters. It should be "auth/facebook/?state=123"

Comment: Thank you for this!! I was hijacking the state parameter to achieve this before reading your answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great feature of omniauth, shame it's not better documented.

Answer (score 22):

I guess the cookie thing works but why do all that when you can use the state variable as documented here: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

This is how I used it:

when creating the url you can just add state in the Query String and it will be available in the callback url as well.

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :display => 'page', :state=>'123') %>
```

now the callback url will be

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback?state=123&code=ReallyLongCode#_=_
```

Now in the callback handler you can process the state

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `:params` options, as in

```
omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, var: 'value', var2: 'value2' )
```

and later in the callback you can access `request.env['omniauth.params']` to get the hash! :)

(copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618951/977116))

Comment: A live-saver, long lasting at the very bottom :)

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do is dynamically set your callback to include the partner name in the url (**not** the url parameters), on a **per authentication transaction** basis, depending on which partner was involved. This means setting the callback url dynamically, for each authentication request. See [this blog post to get started](http://www.kbedell.com/2011/03/08/overriding-omniauth-callback-url-for-twitter-or-facebook-oath-processing/). The callback url automatically drops the url parameters, as you've noticed, so doing this with parameters won't work.

So, if instead of trying to pass the partner name/id in as a parameter (which is dropped), you structured your routes so that the `partner_id` and OmniAuth `provider` were part of the callback url, then you'd have something like:

```
/auth/:omniauth_provider/callback/:partner_id
```

...where a valid callback would be something like

```
/auth/facebook/callback/123456
```

...then you would know that a given callback came in from facebook, with partner id `123456`

Comment: Nice answer, Normalocity. I was trying to figure this out myself. I'm not quite sure how to do what you prescribed above and the blog post doesn't shed that much light either. Would you be able to post some code? Specifically, how would generate this route described above and how would one create the respective controller actions to handle the different callbacks? I specifically want the callback to provide context of where the user left from, that way I can return the user to where they were once OAuth is complete.

Comment: The url where the user "left from" can be stored in a cookie as they're being redirected to the oauth portal, when when the callback returns, the cookie can be looked up, the value retrieved, and the cookie expired/deleted. As for the other stuff, I think it might be a good idea for me to roll a quick demo app and post it as a proof of concept, and then I can share the code on github. Then, assuming it works, I can post the code back here in the answer. Give me a few hours to take a crack at it.

Answer (score 6):

OmniAuth already has a built-in way to know where the user was, it's called "origin" as documented here:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Saving-User-Location

Answer (score 1):

You know, I think I might be trying to solve this the hard way.

Cookies might be the answer. I think you can solve this by having your login action store a cookie, and then redirecting to the proper `/auth/:provider` path for authentication, and when the callback is triggered (in `SessionsController#create`), you just read the cookie back to know where to redirect them to.

So, right now, your "login with facebook" link (or whatever you have you in your app) probably goes to `/auth/facebook`. Instead if you created a custom action like

```
POST /partner_auth
```

...and called it with the url...

```
POST example.com/partner_auth?from=partner&provider=facebook
```

Then you might have a controller like:

```
class PartnerAuth < ApplicationController
  def create
    cookies[:from] = params[:from]  # creates a cookie storing the "from" value
    redirect_to "auth/#{params[:provider]"
  end
end
```

Then in the `SessionsController#create` action, you would have...

```
def create
  ...

  destination = cookies[:from]
  cookies[:from].delete

  redirect_to destination    # or whatever the appropriate thing is for your
                             # app to do with the "from" information
end
```

I tried to build a demo app to accomplish what I'd outlined in the other answer, but you're right - it was too complicated to try to dynamically inject a custom callback into the OmniAuth code. There is a configuration option to override the default callback, but it doesn't appear to be easy to set it dynamically.

So, it dawned on me that cookies would be way simpler, user-specific, and since you theoretically only need to store this `from` information for a very short time (between when the user tries to authenticate, and when the  callback is triggered), it's no big deal to create a cookie, and then delete it when the callback gets hit.

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'state' Variable. Facebook allows the user to set a STATE variable.

Here is how I did it, I appended the AUTH URL with ?state=providername

```
http://localhost/users/auth/facebook?state=providername
```

This param is returned to me at Callback as params['providername']

I devised the solution from the original Omniauth Path Method

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :display => 'page', :state=>'123') %>
```

Comment: This is very bad approach. The state parameter is there to avoid token forgery from another domain. The state is a generated key that is passed with the user to the IDP and is returned by the IDP so you can double-check that this auth request was really made by your server.