# How to use omniauth-facebook 2 times on same page in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am developing `rails 4` application.

I required `two facebook buttons` on index page where `1 for facebook sign up` and `other for facebook login`.

`Scenario 1:` If user click on `FB sign up button`, the user register's using omniauth and gets redirected to a form for further signup details as per the project flow.

`Scenario 2:` If user click on `FB login button`, User is authenticated through omniauth and is redirected to home page

I can manage 1 button using `omniauth` but how to manage second one. How  i know which button user click.

Any way to i can pass any `parameter to facebook` and FB return it when response us.

Any thing else

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got solutions for this particualar question.

I pass params in facebook.js.coffee.erb

jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('')

$.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true

window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>', cookie: true)

```
 $('#sign_up').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback?UserClk=signup' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback?UserClk=signin' if response.authResponse
```

$('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true

You can check on above code which i highlight.

For 2 buttons i set 2 ids where sign_in & sign_out

Pass just params in callback url which i got when response back from facebook.

Now you can do your process using params in controller.

Many thanks to all whose try for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides only one callback URL. So no matter what how many buttons you have, you will get the redirection to one specific action. And also you don't need two separate buttons though. You could have the sign-in and sign-up done through Facebook with one button. When you get the callback you could check the email attribute in the request hash and find out if the user is registered user or a new user and act with your logic accordingly. Here's a sample code. The authorisation table is used to store Facebook details.

```
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
@authorization = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
if @authorization
  @authorization.token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']
  @authorization.save!
  sign_in_and_redirect User.find(@authorization.user_id)
  #render :text => "Welcome back #{@authorization.user.name}! You have already signed up."
else
  @user = User.find_by_email(auth_hash["info"]["email"])
  if @user
    @user.authorizations.create!(:provider => auth_hash['provider'], :uid => auth_hash['uid'], :token => auth_hash['credentials']['token'])
    @user.save
  else
    @user = User.new :first_name => auth_hash["info"]["first_name"], :last_name => auth_hash["info"]["last_name"], :email => auth_hash["info"]["email"] , :fb_profile_url => auth_hash["info"]["image"], :validated => true
    @user.authorizations.build :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"], :token => auth_hash['credentials']['token']
    @user.save
  end
  sign_in_and_redirect @user
end
```

Comment: Yes code is right but How i can identifier that user click on which button. Because when user click on FB login in button then only want to check that user register through FB or not. Not want to register when click on sign in button. User register only when they click on FB sign up button if not exists. Make sense.

Comment: Do you really want two buttons when you can do the registration as well as Sign-in using a single button. You can check out popular sites which provides fb sign-in and they don't have a different buttons.

Comment: Yes but its a client requirements.

Comment: May be its possible through pass parameter and get that back and identify on which button user did a click

Comment: I don't think you can pass parameters with the Facebook oauth link. The link takes you outside your domain and after authentications brings you back.

Comment: Check it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890985/passing-parameters-through-omniauth

Comment: Great!! I did not know this. Hopefully should solve your problem :-)