# OmniAuth Post-Create Callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have to run some code (subscription to an external mailing list) when a new user is created with OmniAuth (any strategy). The setup is pretty much identical to Ryan Bates' screencast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast

So far I haven't found a suitable point to hook in the code in the middleware. And when control is returned to the Rails level, the data is passed as `user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])` and nothing indicates whether the user has just been created or not.

A workaround could be a flag on the user which defaults to false and is set to true in session#create. But there has to be a better way, hasn't there? :-)

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: A slightly more elegant workaround: Check the `current_user.created_at` timestamp after the callback to session#create and consider the user as newly created if the timestamp is no older than say 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:params` option to build a URL, like this

```
omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, {var: 'value', var2: 'value2'}
```

and then in the callback you will get in back in the request.env['omniauth.params']

Some examples here - https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/390

Also here- [Passing random url params to OmniAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999907/passing-random-url-params-to-omniauth)

Comment: I don't use Devise, so no `omniauth_authorize_path`. I could add params in the config, but it wouldn't help telling after the callback whether the user existed before or not.