# Rails Beta invitations - Overriding Devise Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, railscasts, invitation

I use Devise (1.4.8) for my User model and have been trying to implement a simple beta invitation feature (Rails 3.0.7), following Ryan Bates's [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations).

**I can't get the [new] method of my devise model's controller to recognize the invitation token.** I suspect this is because I am not succesfully overriding the registrations controller of Devise.

I am assuming instead of the using the user_controller for passing variables from registration form, I have to override devise's registrations controller. So my registrations_controller.rb in the root of controllers folder:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    @user = User.new(:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token])
    @user.email = @user.invitation.recipient_email if @user.invitation
  end
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'} do
  get 'users/sign_up/:invitation_token' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => "new_user_registration"
end
```

In invitation_controller.rb

```
Mailer.invitation(@invitation, new_user_registration_url+"/#{@invitation.token}").deliver
```

**How I can override Devise's registration controller and pass the :invitation_token successfully from Devise's new user form?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon some more research, I found others running into a similar problem:

- [Devise + Omniauth - How to pass extra parameters along?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along)
- [Custom Query Paramaters for Omniauth callbacks](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omniauth/TZnWCK-QSHk)

The real issue was I was trying to pass a variable to one of Omniauth's callback methods. I was not able to figure out how to do that. As a workaround, I ended up using a session variable and accessed it from within the Omniauth callback method.

Not very elegant, but did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What if you dump params[:invitation_token] in your controller? Do you have the param?

You should use 'registrations#new', not 'devise/registrations#new' in your routes