# Omniauth - set custom param in redirect url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm using latest (1.0.1) version of Omniauth with rails 3.1.3.
Right now, I'm using omniauth with 37signals strategy. I would like to pass custom argument ("state" parameter) depending on  auth url (eg. http://localhost:3000/auth/37signals/**5** should redirect to https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new?(...)**&state=5**

I've tried to set (temporarily) fixed state, with something like

```
provider "37signals", "my_client_id", "my_secret", {state: "5"}
```

However, in my url there is (still) no state param.
Any ideas why? Is it possible to set that param?

Answer (score 4):

when creating the url you can just add state in the Query String and it will be available in the callback url as well.

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, :display => 'page', :state=>'123') %>
```

now the callback url will be

```
http://localhost:3000/consumers/auth/facebook/callback?state=123&code=ReallyLongCode#_=_
```

Now in the callback handler you can process the state

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `:params` options, as in

```
omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, var: 'value', var2: 'value2' )
```

and later in the callback you can access `request.env['omniauth.params']` to get the hash! :)

(copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618951/977116))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not to appending other params for the url. the server side just like the specify params.

maybe you need to take a look this one.

https://raw.github.com/tallgreentree/omniauth-37signals/e94a70a08c4535abb91338d8ef73593e143f1e5a/lib/omniauth/strategies/37signals.rb