# Invitation based authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm new to ROR and trying to build an invite based auth. Currently, I'm using Omniauth-facebook to have login using fb on my site. However, I want the users to have a custom url like - "www.mysite.com/invite/" which they can share to drive signup. I would also track these referrals so that I could incentivise users to drive such logins. I'm absolutely clueless about how to proceed and any starting pointers would be great.

One way could be to have a route for '/invite/:invite_code' and before the "/auth/facebook" is triggered I could read the invite code and increment the counter but then how do I check if the "/auth/facebook" was called from the invite page only. Does this sound correct? Or are there better solutions out there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make a POST to `auth/facebook` having more or less this code in you OmniAuth callbacks controller:

```
def facebook
  Invitation.increment if request.env['omniauth.params'][:from_invitation_page]
  # OR
  # Invitation.increment if request.env['omniauth.origin'].match /your_invitation_url/
```

See that:

```
request.env['omniauth.origin']
```

is set automatically, while:

```
request.env['omniauth.params']
```

is set rendering a link like:

```
omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, var: 'value', var2: 'value2' )
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along)

Comment: So what this means is that I add extra params at the end of redirect_uri on /auth/facebook/callback? eg... `/auth/facebook?invitation=123456`

Comment: one of the options? yes