# ruby on rails + devise + oauth2 - Register / Sign In and submit other data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, oauth-2.0

Forgive the title - I'm not 100% sure how to summarize the question.

My application is a Rails 4 app, using Devise with Oauth2. The goal of the app is a simple questionnaire, with one question.  As the "submit" button of the form, I would like to have a button that is "sign up / sign in" with Facebook.

I have Oauth2 working with Facebook - it creates an account (if one doesn't exist), etc. - but what I can't figure out is how to pass the `answer_id` and `question_id` past the Oauth2 call in order to persist that to the database after the user has successfully authenticated with Facebook.

I understand that I can pass custom key/value pairs to the `omniauth_authorize_path` call in Devise, but that seems like it might be problematic as I'd have to use JavaScript to determine the option chosen by the user. I'm specifically referencing [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657727/devise-omniauth-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-along) with regards to this possible solution.

So, I guess my questions are, is the above the right idea and just pass `answer_id` and `question_id` through `omniauth_authorize_path` and read it after, or is there another solution, perhaps a POST to /answers, which would somehow make an Oauth2 call in my AnswersController?

Additional information that might be helpful:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```